Staging Ground is Mislabeled on the releases page of the blog
As I understand it, the staging ground is an initiative primarily around the public Stack Overflow site.
On the releases page of the blog, it’s labelled with a logo for Stack Overflow for Teams (SOfT),
 as opposed to the regular Stack Overflow-related posts as shown here by a post about discussions:

While I'm glad to see a deeply popular, and important community centric tool get center stage, unless it is a tool for SOfT (which as a product got decoupled from SO) - it would be less confusing if didn't have a prominent logo for Stack Overflow for Teams.
